# How to fix python float numbers exponential result

Tags: c#, python, double, decimal

I was playing with datatypes in python.

Every time, when I do

`remaining_amount  = .1 + .1 + .1 - .3`

python gives an exponential result.

I try to do the same with c#

`double remainingAmount = .1 + .1 + .1 - .3`

It is also giving result in exponential form.

In both cases, the result is **5.55111512312578E-17**

But in **c#**, when I **change double to decimal, the result is 0.0**

I am unable to understand why this is happening in both languages. 
And how can I fix this in python?

Comment: Why don't you try decimal.TryParse(remaining) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Netwave is correct, as you wanted to fix this in python, the way would be `decimal` module:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal('.1') + Decimal('.1') + Decimal('.1') - Decimal('.3')
Decimal('0.0')
>>> float(Decimal('.1') + Decimal('.1') + Decimal('.1') - Decimal('.3'))
0.0
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

That is the Python representation of the number, the number is still the same.
You can format a string with it for printing purpouses for example:

```
>>> remaining_amount  = .1 + .1 + .1 - .3
>>> remaining_amount
5.551115123125783e-17
>>> f"{remaining_amount:.50f}"
'0.00000000000000005551115123125782702118158340454102'
```